# android plugin issue, asks to update, but already updated all

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I know this has been asked before as well, but I have done all I can.
I  have updated all I can from SDK  manager, but still I am getting this issue with my project that I just created.

There is no functionality I have given yet, but the issue says the plugin is too old, please update or change the `ANDROID_DAILY_ENVIRONMENT` variable.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.manav.loginapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: Whats your Android Studio version?

Comment: Please also provide your project level build.gradle file.

Comment: @Jacob // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @Rosario its Android 2.2 beta 2

Comment: You should try using a stable version instead of beta. I recommend downloading Android Studio 2.2 Stable Version: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: @Rosario I would consider that answer, thanks but also my one other project I am working on with lower version of support libraries is working fine, but as soon as i created this new one, the issue occurred,

Comment: @manvendradubey please edit your question so you can format code properly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  thanks for the suggestion,
Anyways got it resolved by downloading the new version and then updating the classpath (since updating alone didnt worked out)